# Angular, display array in array using service

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I get all data json from ws like this:

```
{
  "StatusCode":0,
  "StatusMessage":"OK",
  "StatusDescription":   
   [
      {"homeboxpackage_id":"1",
        "active":0,
        "homebox_id":"11",
        "serial_number":"serialn1",
        "user_id":"31", 
        "sensors": { 
              "0":{
                    "sensor_serial":"sensorserial1",
                    "sensors_id":"11E805BA6732C3DB"
              }, 
              "1":{
                    "sensor_serial":"sensorserial2", 
                    "sensors_id":"11E805BA6F1E6CE9"
              }, 
              "2":{
                    "sensor_serial":"sensorserial3", 
                    "sensors_id":"11E805BA7716C775"
              }
        }
    }
  ]
```

In html code, I want to display data sensors in list, but dosn't show. My html code:

```
  <table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]="homeboxsp | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
    [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <mfDefaultSorter by="serial_number">Serial Number</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th>
          <mfDefaultSorter by="sensors">Sensor Serial</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp">
        <td>{{item.serial_number}}</td>
        <ul>
          <li>{{item.sensors}}</li>
        </ul>
        <td>{{item.active}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

homeboxsp is in component.ts

> ```
>  this.ws.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
>       homeboxsp => {
>         this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp; // in console display all my array in array
>            }
>     );
> ```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBVSc.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxRTr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBVSc.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another **`ngFor`** to loop sensor objects

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp">
        <td>{{item.serial_number}}</td>
        <ng-container *ngFor= "let sensor of item.sensors">
        <ul>
          <li>{{sensor.sensors_id}}</li>
        </ul>
        <td>{{item.active}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. :(

Comment: post your json array

Comment: {"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription": [{"homeboxpackage_id":"1","active":0,"homebox_id":"11","serial_number":"serialn1","user_id":"31", "sensors":{ "0":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial1", "sensors_id":"11E805BA6732C3DB"}, "1":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial2", "sensors_id":"11E805BA6F1E6CE9"}, "2":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial3", "sensors_id":"11E805BA7716C775"}}}]

Comment: you need to change the response as array, in this sensors is an object

Comment: did you sort this issue?

Comment: Its ok now! Thank you :)

Comment: The problem was to json. The sensors were objects. Now JSON is: {"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription":
 [{"sensors":
 [{
 "sensor_serial":"sensorserial1",
 "sensors_id":"11E805BA673"},
 {
 "sensor_serial":"sensorserial2",
 "sensors_id":"11E805BA6F1"},
 {
 "sensor_serial":"sensorserial3",
 "sensors_id":"11E805BA7716"}]
 ,"homeboxpackage_id":"11E805BA8AF2B29",
 "active":1,
 "homebox_id":"11E805BA4238970",
 "date_created":"2018-01-30T12:38:58.000Z",
 "date_modified":"2018-01-30T16:13:58.000Z",
 "serial_number":"serialn1", "user_id":"3100000"}] You were right

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse response as a json in order to use actual response body. res.json will extract the body data and return it to the subscribe. Make sure you import rxjs library first.

```
//import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
  //import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  //import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

this.ws.homeboxPGetAll().map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
  homeboxsp => {
    this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp.sensors;
       }
);
```

Comment: ws is this:     public homeboxPGetAll(): Observable<HomeboxP[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.homeboxPGetAll), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();

        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(homeboxP => {
            return new HomeboxP(homeboxP);
          });
        }
      });
  }